# How to groupBy using multiple columns in scala collections

Tags: scala, collections

```
records.groupBy(_.column1)
```

What if I want to include more columns like if I want to group by column1, column2 and column3?

Any hints?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you add an example ?

Comment: see my records is a list of records having column1 , column2, column3 and so on. And i want to group by the result using groupby column1, column2

Comment: I don't see what is a multi-column grouping, I was asking for a concrete exampe

Comment: RawData contains name,course etc columns

val data = records.asInstanceOf[List[RawData]]
val finalResult = data.groupBy(_.name)

Comment: Arg, this is still not an example !!! Could you just give an input, a query, and your expected output ? You know, it's for you : the clearer is your question, the sooner you will have answers

Comment: this was just a code extract from a bigger project and am trying to modify that also am new to scala    https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/110 do you have an idea that is this correct? we cant use mutliple keys. But in my case i have got the result and i want to do a group by on it using two columns eg in sql you do group the result eg group by name,course

Comment: Wait a sec, are you asking about scala collections, or slick? Please [edit] your question to include all these details.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try

```
records.groupBy(record => (record.column1, record.column2, record.column3))
```

This will group by a tuple composed of those 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working for me. All the examples i saw was using only 1 group by and i was not getting how to use multiple columns. Can you point me to some basics around this so that i can understand this better. also thanks @Dici sorry for not being able to paste the exact code base.

Comment: As a basic explanation. When using groupBy, you're providing a function that takes in an item of the type that its being called on, and returns an item representing the group that it should be go in. groupBy iterates on all elems building the new collection. eg. if you had two Record objects with fields col1, col2, col3 - values "a", "b", "c" for the first, and "a", "b", "x" for the second. The first will return a tuple ("a", "b", "c"), then put it into its own group. The second will return a tuple ("a", "b", "x"), which is different to the first tuple, and thus goes into its own group.

Comment: What is the difference between `record` and `records`?

Comment: You can't tell from the code subset provided, but presumably records is some sort of List[Record] object, which would make record a Record object. ie. groupBy is operating on the items inside the list.